# Is it possible to unwrap array in a method call in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this code:

```
def foo( arg_array ) 
  arg_array.each do |ar|
    puts ar
  end
end 

my_array = ["Hello", "Bye", "Please"]

foo my_array # Works fine
foo "Thanks", my_array # And this not
```

Is there any way to do method calls like the second one without joining directly with `"Thanks"`?

Comment: arg_array = {}? {} is a hash. Anyway: ["Thanks", *my_array].

Comment: Yes, I've changed.
And thank you for the answer, it was exactly what I've searched for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splat array unpack:

```
foo ["Thanks", *my_array]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick and clean way to add elements onto an existing array, you can use:

```
foo ["Thanks"] + my_array
```

which creates a one-element array containing `"Thanks"`, then concatenates the contents of `my_array` onto it.  You can check it out in IRB if you like:

```
my_array = ["Hello", "Bye", "Please"]
=> ["Hello", "Bye", "Please"]
["Thanks"] + my_array
=> ["Thanks", "Hello", "Bye", "Please"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept any number of `String` or `Array` and treat them as a single array, you can use this:

```
def foo(*arg_array)
  arg_array = arg_array.map { |arg| arg.is_a?(Array) ? arg : [arg] }.flatten(1)
  arg_array.each do |ar|
    puts ar
  end
end 

my_array = ["Hello", "Bye", "Please"]

foo my_array # print Hello Bye Please
foo "Thanks", my_array # prints Thanks Hello Bye Please
```

Comment: Thanks, nice advice, but the goal is just to find the way to call an existing method.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept to change the method, this method will work for arrays or for single objects:

```
def foo(*args)
  args.each do |ar|
    puts ar
  end
end
```

***args** will transform single objects into arrays

```
foo 'thanks'
# => prints 'thanks'
foo ['bar', 'baz', 'foobar']
# => prints 'bar'
# => prints 'baz'
# => prints 'foobar'
```

If you dont want to change the method, you can add thanks to the array en each call

```
foo ['Thanks'] + ['to','you']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Just add the splat operator (`*`) for the `arg_array` in the method definition:

```
def foo( *arg_array ) 
  arg_array.each do |ar|
    puts ar
  end
end 

my_array = ["Hello", "Bye", "Please"]

foo my_array             # Works fine
foo "Thanks", my_array   # And this also
```